# LVM2: pvscan with offset?

Tags: linux, raid, lvm, disaster-recovery

After [I played with mdadm a bit too hard](https://superuser.com/questions/864149/mdadm-grow-from-raid1-to-raid10), I'm now tryng to recover my lvm2 volumes that were sitting in the original RAID1 array. pvscan finds nothing, but that's not a surprise: since mdadm is not able to rebuild the array, pvscan has no /dev/md1 to look at.

However I know (er... I hope) my lvm2 volumes are still there, I think I only zapped the raid metadata.

My idea is to losetup /dev/sdc2 under /dev/loop1 with an offset using a live sysresccd, so that I skip the broken RAID metadata in /dev/sdc2 and reach the PV itself. I plan something like:

```
losetup -o xxxxxx /dev/loop1 /dev/sdc2
pvscan
```

Then pvscan can find the volume in /dev/loop1. The problem is that I don't know the offset (but that can be overcome by studying or by trial and error) and, most importantly, that losetup does not work with physical devices. How can I create a device that points to another device with an offset? Or, how can I make pvscan look for physical volumes using an offset?

EDIT after @lsd comment:

When I tried:

```
losetup -o 32256 /dev/loop1 /dev/sdc2
```

I got:

```
losetup: /dev/sdc2: warning: file smaller than 512 bytes, the loop device maybe be useless or invisible for system tools.
```

and I assumed the warning was telling me something was wrong, because /dev/sdc2 is smaller than 512 bytes only if you consider it as a normal file, but if losetup supported block devices it should know its real size... should I ignore the warning nevertheless?

Comment: I see according to the losetup man pages (rhel6.5) that it accepts both a physical device, and a data offset using the -o parameter.  Did you try that?

Comment: @lsd have you got a link to said RHEL manpage? Losetup manpage in sysresccd 3.5.7 does not tell anything about physical devices.

Comment: This is the manpage to losetup on rhel6.5 dated 2003-07-01, from util-linux-ng rpm.  As the man page is old it may not be that accurate.  I've been looking for lvm information also...

Comment: Everything I'm seeing suggests it would be easier to dd the disk into a file on another hard drive (in addition to being safer), then try to mount from the image.

Comment: Following your advice, I assumed losetup supported physical devices and I found the correct offset, which is in my case 134152192. If you turn your comment into an answer I'll accept it, thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`losetup` works just fine on device files.  At least on Ubuntu 14.04.  Linux 3.13.0-43-generic with util-linux 2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.  And with 2.26-rc1 from git.

```
sudo losetup -o 32256 /dev/loop5 /dev/sdb3
sudo tail -c 32257 /dev/sdb3 | sudo cmp - /dev/loop5
```

(for some reason, process substitution doesn't work: `sudo cmp <(sudo tail -c 32257 /dev/sdb3) /dev/loop5`.  "cmp: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory")

I'm not using lvm anymore on this system.  I don't remember LVM breaking normal loopback devices.  Unless it does some form of locking on the plain block devices, so they can't be used directly.